# How do I correctly subscribe to a PropertyChange event of another class?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am attempting to bind a CheckBox in my View to a property in my ViewModel.  I am trying to subscribe to changes of the individual ViewModel property.

I have implemented INotifyPropertyChanged on my custom class, however my handler method is never called.

I have included basic examples of the View (XAML), ViewModel, and the custom user class.

## ViewModel

```
public class HomeViewModel: ViewModelBase
{
    public HomeViewModel()
    {
        this.selectedUser = new usersVM();       
        this.selectedUser.PropertyChanged += propChangedHandler;
    }

    private void propChangedHandler(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "superuser")  // <-- breakpoint here
        {

        }
    }

        private usersVM _selectedUser;
        public usersVM selectedUser
        {
            get { return this._selectedUser; }
            set
            {
                if (this._selectedUser != value)
                {
                    this._selectedUser = value;
                    this.RaisePropertyChanged("selectedUser");
                }
            }
        }
}
```

## Custom User Class

```
public class usersVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public usersVM()
    {
        this.hasChanges = false;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    private int _superuser;
    public int superuser 
    {
        get
        {
            return this._superuser;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value != this._superuser)
            {
                this._superuser = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("username");
            }
        }
    }
```

## XAML #

```
<CheckBox Margin="0,0,8,0" Content="SuperUser"  IsChecked="{Binding superuser}" DataContext="{Binding selectedUser}" />
```

I have a breakpoint in my Hadler Method to try to verify when the event is handled, but this is never called.

How can I properly implement INotifyPropertyChanged and subscribe to these events in my ViewModel?

Comment: What are you talking about? There isn't even an `enabled` property in your usersVM  class. As a note, in the selectedUser property setter you should detach propChangedHandler from the old property value and attach it to the new one.

Comment: Fixed that mistake.  Can you share an example of what you are describing here?

Comment: Why is superUser an `int` instead of `bool`? For the PropertyChangedHandler, you have `this.selectedUser.PropertyChanged += propChangedHandler`. Now imagine what happens when you assign a new value to `selectedUser`.

Comment: This class is used to map an Entity Framework class to update a database, the database is using int 1/0 for bool.  That is why.

Answer (score 0):

Detach the PropertyChanged event handler from the current selectedUser value and attach it to the new one like this:

```
private usersVM _selectedUser;
public usersVM selectedUser
{
    get { return _selectedUser; }
    set
    {
        if (_selectedUser != value)
        {
            if (_selectedUser != null)
            {
                _selectedUser.PropertyChanged -= propChangedHandler; 
            }
            _selectedUser = value;
            if (_selectedUser != null)
            {
                _selectedUser.PropertyChanged += propChangedHandler; 
            }
            RaisePropertyChanged("selectedUser");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for updating this.  I was hoping you would answer so that I could accept, but I appreciate the help.